# dozer: How to convert generic field

Tags: java, generics, converters, dozer

I am a new dozer user.
When I convert ProductInfo to ProductDto, throw a exception.
the error message is :

> class has no fields.

There is a generic field: `TrialInfo<Amount>` trialInfo,is there any way to convert this product model?

```
public class ProductInfo implements Serializable{
   private PriceInfo priceInfo;
   public priceInfo getPriceInfo() {
        return priceInfo;
    }

    public void setPriceInfo(PriceInfo priceInfo) {
        this.priceInfo = priceInfo;
    }
}

public class PriceInfo implements Serializable {

    private TrialInfo<Amount> trialInfo;
   public TrialInfo<Amount> getTrialInfo() {
        return trialInfo;
    }

    public void setTrialInfo(TrialInfo<Amount> trialInfo) {
        this.trialInfo = trialInfo;
    }
}
public class TrialInfo<AmountT> implements Serializable {

    private AmountT trialAmount;
    public AmountT getTrialAmount() {
        return trialAmount;
    }

    public void setTrialAmount(AmountT trialAmount) {
        this.trialAmount = trialAmount;
    }
}

public class Amount implements Serializable {

    private int storage;

    public int getStorage() {
        return storage;
    }

    public void setStorage(int storage) {
        this.storage = storage;
    }

}
```